# How to "merge" rows along with their foreign many-to-many relations without violating unique constraints?

Tags: postgresql, update, unique-constraint, relations, postgresql-13

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/-JLFuIrN

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE folders (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE file_folders (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  file_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES files,
  folder_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES folders,
  UNIQUE (file_id, folder_id)
);
```

### Query

```
/*
  Merges
*/

WITH targets AS (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        folders TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (50)
      LIMIT 3
    ) AS folders
),
-- basically a setup to ensure unique target/folder pairs
-- and no targets in the merges
input_folders AS (
  SELECT
    folders.id AS folder_id,
    random_array_element(targets.folders) AS target_id
  FROM
    folders
    CROSS JOIN
    targets
  WHERE
    NOT ( 
      folders.id = ANY (targets.folders)
    ) 
),
input_files AS (
  SELECT
    file_folders.id,
    file_folders.folder_id,
    file_folders.file_id,
    input_folders.target_id
  FROM
    input_folders
    INNER JOIN
    file_folders
    ON
      input_folders.folder_id = file_folders.folder_id
      OR
      input_folders.target_id = file_folders.folder_id
),
deleted_files AS (
    WITH deletions AS (
    SELECT
      inputs.id
    FROM
      input_files AS inputs
      INNER JOIN
      input_files AS targets
      ON
        NOT (inputs.folder_id = targets.target_id)
        AND
        inputs.file_id = targets.file_id
  )
  DELETE
  FROM
    file_folders
  WHERE
    id IN (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM
        deletions
    )
),
merged_files AS (
  WITH merges AS (
    SELECT
      inputs.id,
      inputs.folder_id,
      inputs.target_id
    FROM
      input_files AS inputs
      INNER JOIN
      input_files AS targets
      ON
        NOT (inputs.folder_id = targets.target_id)
        AND
        NOT (inputs.file_id = targets.file_id)
  )
  UPDATE file_folders
  SET
    folder_id = merges.target_id
  FROM
    merges
  WHERE
    merges.id = file_folders.id
),
deleted_folders AS (
  DELETE
  FROM
    folders
  WHERE
    id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        folder_id
      FROM
        input_folders
    )
)
SELECT
  folders AS targets
FROM
  targets
;
```

### Inputs

The array-transforming setup is me trying to replicate the JSON input of the application in pure SQL.
The input looks like this:

```typescript
interface IQueryInput extends Array<IMergeInput> {};

interface IMergeInput {
  target: IEntityID;
  inputs: IEntityID[];
};

// postgresql bigints are treated as strings in the application
type IEntityID = string;
```

So the prepping query from above can be replaced with:

```
WITH inputs AS (
  SELECT
    input.*
  FROM
    -- the application interpolates JSON there
    json_to_recordset($inputs$$inputs$) AS input(
      target bigint,
      inputs bigint[]
    )
),
input_folders AS (
  SELECT
    inputs.target AS target_id,
    merge.folder_id
  FROM
    inputs
    CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(inputs.inputs) AS merge(
      folder_id
    )
)
```

It must run as a batch operation, so the application provides these guaranties for the query input:

- all `target` values are unique.
- all `inputs` concatenated result in unique values.
- `target` values do not intersect with concatenated `inputs`.
  Therefore `input_folders` always ends up as unique `target_id`-`folder_id` pairs.

The query is ran as a background task, so the speed and memory are of secondary importance.
The main requirement is of a typical transaction: either it should go through completely on success or reject completely on any error.

### The problem

I want to "merge" several folders into a single folder. So given a `target_id` and an array of `folder_id`s, replace all foreign references to `folder_id`s with `target_id` and remove non-target folder afterwards.
This however becomes an issue in relations table with unique constraints, since after updating the references there are duplicates.
So I went this path:

1. Select all relation rows related to the query, so all `file_folders` with `target_id`s and `folder_id`s in them.
2. Separate them into two categories:

   - `Deletes` - the rows which will result in dupes when updated.
   - `Merges` - the rows which will not result in.
3. Delete the delete candidates.
4. Update the merge candidates.
5. Repeat previous 4 steps for all relations.
6. Delete rows in `folders` with `folder_id`s.

However I still stumble upon unique key violation error.
"Merge" is in quotes because it doesn't look like what I am trying to do can be accomplished by [merge in docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) and it requires a newer version of postgresql anyway.

Comment: Your explanation speaks of a "single target folder" But the code tries to merge all existing folders into one of three arbitrarily chosen target folders. Please clarify. Also, since you are updating most rows in table `file_folders` anyway, is it an option to just create a new table `file_folders_new`, then drop the old one and rename the new one? Typically faster ...

Comment: I forgot to mention details in regards to inputs, but the crutch is it is supposed to be able run non-intersecting merges in a batch. I edited the question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it burns down to just this to create your new table `file_folders`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (2, 3)
       i.id, i.file_id, COALESCE(random_array_element(t.folders), i.folder_id)
FROM   file_folders  i
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT ARRAY (SELECT id FROM folders TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (50) LIMIT 3)) t(folders) ON i.folder_id <> ALL (t.folders)
ORDER  BY 2, 3, 1;
```

Using `DISTINCT ON` to remove duplicates. I chose to keep the row with the smallest `id` value. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

If you can afford an exclusive lock, the cheapest way will be to create a new table from this like:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE file_folders, folders, files IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

-- temp table for targets for multiple uses!
CREATE TEMP TABLE targets AS
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT id FROM folders TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI (50) LIMIT 3) AS folders;

CREATE TABLE file_folders_new AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (2, 3)
       i.id, i.file_id, COALESCE(random_array_element(t.folders), i.folder_id) AS folder_id
FROM   file_folders i
LEFT   JOIN targets t ON i.folder_id <> ALL (t.folders)
ORDER  BY 2, 3, 1;

-- make sure the new table is good HERE !

DROP  TABLE file_folders;
ALTER TABLE file_folders_new RENAME TO file_folders;
ALTER TABLE file_folders
  ADD CONSTRAINT file_folders_file_id_fkey   FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files
, ADD CONSTRAINT file_folders_folder_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders
, ADD CONSTRAINT file_folders_uni UNIQUE (file_id, folder_id)
, ADD CONSTRAINT file_folders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)  -- do you need the surrogate PK?
, ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;

-- sync sequence of new IDETNTITY
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('file_folders', 'id'), COALESCE(max(id), 1), false))
FROM file_folders;

-- recreate all other indexes etc. your org. table file_folders had HERE !

-- drop orphaned folders
DELETE FROM folders f
USING  targets t
WHERE  f.id <> ALL (t.folders);

COMMIT;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iDZpMsCr)

All in a single transaction, so you don't lose data if anything goes wrong.

Alternatively (to avoid recreating constraints and indexes) you could create a temp table for `file_folders`, `TRUNCATE` the old one, and `INSERT` rows from the temp table. See:

- [Best way to delete millions of rows by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8290958/939860)

But when updating most rows, it's typically cheaper to recreate all indexes from scratch than incrementally udating all rows.

Related:

- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)
- [PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL random value from array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328164/939860)

Comment: Is temp table a good idea? It might work for the example in the question, but the real relation tables are going to have a lot more columns, such as creation/update timestamps, auth info, publication state info. Because it's important who, when and how added these relations, they have the primary keys too. I chose to slim them down for the example in order not to bloat an already complex query.
Not to mention the query will require to be in sync with the actual migrations, indexes, triggers, and the checked in copy of SQL declarations in the repository. So I guess temp tables is noop.

Comment: @BillerBuilder: You mean the tiny temp table in the code, or a temp table as stepping stone for `file_folders`? For the latter, it makes sense if you must  keep the existing table in place. Might as well be a regular table if you can't spare enough RAM for a temporary one.

Comment: It is a tiny code, but it is the code I'd have to write for every single related relation table in the queries and also keep synced with schema definitions. Which is extra tricky because the table definitions in this query are deferred, so it's even harder to tell at glance if they conform to main definitions or not.
Also I am pretty sure this approach is riddled with bugs related to lost/errant references, so I'd rather keep table definition modifications to migration scripts.